# How to configure containers in one network to connect to each other (server -> mysql)?

Tags: docker, port, docker-container

I have ran ubuntu docker-containers (mysql) and (nodejs server app) on windows

> docker run -d --network bridge --name own -p 80:3000 own:latest
>
> docker run -d --name mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345678 mysql:5
>
> docker ps

```js
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
3ce966e43414        own:latest          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->3000/tcp                own
ed10cfc93dd5        mysql:5             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysql
```

When i open port localhost:3000 with server app just via cmd (NOT via docker VM) all is good, I see success connection to the docker-container 0.0.0.0:3306, but when i:

> docker start own

check browser 0.0.0.0:80 and i see Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

> docker network ls

```js
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
019f0886d253        bridge              bridge              local
fa1842bad14c        host                host                local
85e7d1e38e14        none                null                local
```

> docker inspect bridge

```js
[
{
    "Name": "bridge",
    "Id": "019f0886d253091c1367863e38a199fe9b539a72ddb7575b26f40d0d1b1f78dc",
    "Created": "2019-11-19T09:15:53.2096944Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "a79ec12c4cc908326c54abc2b47f80ffa3da31c5e735bf5ff2755f23b9d562dd": {
            "Name": "own",
            "EndpointID": "2afc225e29138ff9f1da0f557e9f7659d3c4ccaeb5bfaa578df88a672dac003f",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "ed10cfc93dd5eda7cfb8a26e5e4b2a8ccb4e9db7a4957b3d1048cb93f5137fd4": {
            "Name": "mysql",
            "EndpointID": "ea23d009f959d954269c0554cecf37d01f8fe71481965077f1372df27f05208a",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {
        "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
        "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
    },
    "Labels": {}
}
]
```

maybe could i somehow assign the own container to the bridge network like mysql. After localhost of the mysql container will be seen for own container? Help please what should i do?

Comment: How did you first run the container? If you use the flag "--network $yournetworkhere" on both the mysql and the own containers they should use the same network and therefore be able to reach each other.

Comment: @Ludo21South just reprodused docker run with flag --network bridge for own container, but catch the same, also edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#create network mynetwork
docker network create --subnet 172.17.0.0/16 mynetwork

#create own container (without starting it)
docker create -d --name own -p 80:3000 own:latest

#add own container to the network mynetwork
docker network connect --ip 172.17.0.2 mynetwork own

#start container own
docker start own

#same as above but with different ip
docker create -d --name mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345678 mysql:5
docker network connect --ip 172.17.0.3 mynetwork mysql
docker start mysql
```

when you stop and remove your containers do, you may remove network this way:

```
docker network rm mynetwork
```

or if you don't do it then there is no need to create it again as above but just connect your new/other containers to it.

In your application you should use `172.17.0.3` as the MySQL address.

Comment: Thank you so much! in my way, i just changed config on sever, localhost to 172.17.0.3